# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\scmpb2\vregistaruseradmin.php on line 61

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have checked other responses to this problem but for some reason I can't solve the problem.This is a register user system I am trying to create but I keep getting the **Fatal error: Call to a member function `prepare()` on a non-object** in....Here it is..

```
>   <?php 
  include ("topbar.php");
     if ($_SESSION['user']['nivel_permissoes'] == 1)
    $idregistadopor=$_SESSION['user']['id_login'];
   echo "<div id='topbar'>
  <a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Voltar</a>
  </div>";
  if(!empty($_POST)) 
    { 
        // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty utilizador 
        if(empty($_POST['utilizador'])) 
        { 
            // Note that die() is generally a terrible way of handling user errors 
            // like this.  It is much better to display the error with the form 
            // and allow the user to correct their mistake.  However, that is an 
            // exercise for you to implement yourself. 
            die("<br/><br/><br /> <h2>Por favor entre um nome de utilizador</h2>"); 
        } 

        // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty password 
        if(empty($_POST['password'])) 
        { 
            die("<br/><br/><br /> <h2>Por favor digite uma password</h2>."); 
        } 

        // Make sure the user entered a valid E-Mail address 
        // filter_var is a useful PHP function for validating form input, see: 
        // http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php 
        // http://us.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php 
        if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
        { 
            die("<br/><br/><br /> <h2>E-mail inválido</h2>"); 
        } 

        // We will use this SQL query to see whether the utilizador entered by the 
        // user is already in use.  A SELECT query is used to retrieve data from the database. 
        // :utilizador is a special token, we will substitute a real value in its place when 
        // we execute the query. 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM login 
            WHERE 
                utilizador = :utilizador 
        "; 

        // This contains the definitions for any special tokens that we place in 
        // our SQL query.  In this case, we are defining a value for the token 
        // :utilizador.  It is possible to insert $_POST['utilizador'] directly into 
        // your $query string; however doing so is very insecure and opens your 
        // code up to SQL injection exploits.  Using tokens prevents this. 
        // For more information on SQL injections, see Wikipedia: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':utilizador' => $_POST['utilizador'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        // The fetch() method returns an array representing the "next" row from 
        // the selected results, or false if there are no more rows to fetch. 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

        // If a row was returned, then we know a matching utilizador was found in 
        // the database already and we should not allow the user to continue. 
        if($row) 
        { 
            die("<br/><br/><br /> <h2>Este utilizador já existe !</h2> "); 
        } 

        // Now we perform the same type of check for the email address, in order 
        // to ensure that it is unique. 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM login 
            WHERE 
                email = :email 
        "; 

        $query_params = array( 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 

        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

        if($row) 
        { 
            die("<br/><br/><br /> <h2>Este e-mail já existe!</h2>"); 
        } 

        // An INSERT query is used to add new rows to a database table. 
        // Again, we are using special tokens (technically called parameters) to 
        // protect against SQL injection attacks. 
        $query = " 
            INSERT INTO login ( 
                nomeuser,
                utilizador, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email,
                sector,
                nivel_permissoes,
                data_registo,
                contacto,
                registado_por
            ) VALUES ( 
                :nomeuser,
                :utilizador, 
                :password, 
                :salt, 
                :email,
                :sector,
                :nivelacesso,
                :data_registo,
                :contacto,
                :registado_por

            ) 
        "; 

        // A salt is randomly generated here to protect again brute force attacks 
        // and rainbow table attacks.  The following statement generates a hex 
        // representation of an 8 byte salt.  Representing this in hex provides 
        // no additional security, but makes it easier for humans to read. 
        // For more information: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table 
        $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 

        // This hashes the password with the salt so that it can be stored securely 
        // in your database.  The output of this next statement is a 64 byte hex 
        // string representing the 32 byte sha256 hash of the password.  The original 
        // password cannot be recovered from the hash.  For more information: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function 
        $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 

        // Next we hash the hash value 65536 more times.  The purpose of this is to 
        // protect against brute force attacks.  Now an attacker must compute the hash 65537 
        // times for each guess they make against a password, whereas if the password 
        // were hashed only once the attacker would have been able to make 65537 different  
        // guesses in the same amount of time instead of only one. 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        { 
            $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
        } 

        // Here we prepare our tokens for insertion into the SQL query.  We do not 
        // store the original password; only the hashed version of it.  We do store 
        // the salt (in its plaintext form; this is not a security risk).
            $dateToday = date("m/d/y"); 
             $query_params = array( 
            ':nomeuser' => $_POST['nomeuser'],
            ':utilizador' => $_POST['utilizador'], 
            ':password' => $password, 
            ':salt' => $salt, 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'],
            ':sector' => $_POST['sector'],
            ':nivelacesso' => $_POST['nivelacesso'],
            ':contacto' => $_POST['contacto'],
            ':data_registo' =>$dateToday,
            ':registado_por' =>$idregistadopor,


        ); 

        try 
        { 
            // Execute the query to create the user 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        // This redirects the user back to the login page after they register 
        header("Location: topbar.php"); 

        // Calling die or exit after performing a redirect using the header function 
        // is critical.  The rest of your PHP script will continue to execute and 
        // will be sent to the user if you do not die or exit. 
        die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
    } 
     ?>
```

Comment: have you enabled pdo in your php.ini

Comment: can you please show your connection code ?

Comment: I guess _$db_ will be your db connection, but where do you set the variable _$db_?

Comment: Where is `$db` ? Did you crated the `PDO` object and stored into $db?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem and shows no attempt to locate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of You have not made any database connection in this page where you are using the `prepare` function.

So you need to make the connection first on this page with the variable `$db` as you are using to call the prepare function.

If you are using the PDO then use this command to make connection:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name;","username","password");
```

Comment: You cannot arrive to this decision because there is an `include ("topbar.php");` and it may contain the connection params as well the `session_start()` thing ;)

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran this is perception that it will be. and it will be that there will not be such any code.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create the instance from `PDO` class:

```
$db = new PDO($dns, $username, $password, $options);
```

After that, you can access `$db->prepare('YOUR_QUERY_STRING');`